# How to add a padding to the data to make it acceptable for AES256 encryption algorithm in pycrypto library

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

Can someone tell me how to add a padding to the data to make it acceptable for AES256 encryption algorithm in pycrypto library (Python).

Thanks a lot in advance.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/), it seems that it's up to you, the library user, to pad the data yourself. The documentation states that the block size for AES is always 16 bytes, so you need to pad the data to a multiple of 16 bytes.

How the padding is done depends on the type of the data. For strings the best approach is probably to encode the string to a specific encoding and then take the length of that encoding. That way you're not relying on all characters being represented by an 8-bit codepoint:

```
plaintext = data.encode('utf-8')
l = len(plaintext)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext + ((16 - len%16) * PADDING_BYTE))
```

A similar approach will work when you're data is an array of bytes.

`0` should work fine as the `PADDING_BYTE`, but you need to take care to remove the padding when you're decrypting the data. It might be worth while including the length of the data in the ciphertext, e.g. prepend the length of the data to the plaintext before encryption, but then you need to jump through some hoops to make sure the padding is generated correctly.

**Edit**: oh yes, just like the RFC GregS links to mentions, the standard way of handling the length problem is the use the length of the padding as the padding byte. I.e. if you need 6 bytes of padding the padding byte is `0x06`. Note that if you don't need any padding, you to add a whole block of padding bytes (16 bytes of `0xa0`) so that you can recover the message correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a standard padding scheme, such as the scheme outlined in [PKCS-5](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt), section 6.1.1 step #4 (replace the 8 in that example with 16 if you are using AES).

Answer (score 0):

pycrypto library has been obsolete for a while, i recommend usings  `pycryptodomex` pip install pycryptodomex

```
import base64
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
###################
class Cryptor:
    def __init__(self, key):
      self.SECRET_KEY = str(key).encode("utf-8")
      self.BLOCK_SIZE = 32 # Bytes
      self.CIPHER = AES.new(self.SECRET_KEY, AES.MODE_ECB) # never use ECB in strong systems obviously

    def encrypt(self, text):
       text = str(text).encode("utf-8")
       return base64.b64encode(self.CIPHER.encrypt(pad(text, self.BLOCK_SIZE))).decode("utf-8")
    
    def decrypt(self, encoded_text):
       self.CIPHER = AES.new(self.SECRET_KEY, AES.MODE_ECB)
       return unpad(self.CIPHER.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encoded_text)), self.BLOCK_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
       
cryptor = Cryptor("1234567890123456")
text = "hello world"
text = cryptor.encrypt(text)
print(text)
print(cryptor.decrypt(text))
```